# Не удается запустить пример Tensorflow под Windows

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, установил python 3.5.2 на anacond'у 2.5 под windows 10. Недавно Tensorflow стала работать под windows (с возможностью применения gpu). Поставил ее в окружении python 3.5.2. Простейшие фрагменты типа Session.run, вычисления тензоров работают нормально. Но при запуске запросов к mnist, iris, официальных примерчиков - выдает ошибки. Например при попытке запустить следующие две строчки

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

Такой текст:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py", line 211, in read_data_sets
    SOURCE_URL + TRAIN_IMAGES)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py", line 141, in maybe_download
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(source_url, temp_file_name)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 198, in urlretrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpv_0xsfi_'
```

Пробовал запускать из командной строки, сделав питон запускаемым из-под администратора - то же самое. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает, если ставить по этому туториалу http://bottomstack.com/installing-tensorflow-windows-and-visual-studio/

1) [Ставим питон отсюда](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2-amd64.exe) обязательно при установке ставим галочку на Add python as PATH
2) [CUDA отсюда](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
3) [соответствующий версии CUDA cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) скачиваем, распаковываем в C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0
4) перезагружаем компьютер
5) заходим в командную строку и копируем 
**pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**

Comment: Вы можете указать в ответе необходимые шаги? Ссылка может со временем стать недоступной...